# jQuery input forms issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on some input forms in JavaScript, and I've edited by script so that once the user enters the number of forces for a problem, new input text fields show up per number, also there is a button which is added at the end of that. The issue is when I try and click this button, I try and use the .map function to start all text field values into it and nothing is happening.

```
function forceRecording(numofforces,$this){
    var addRows='<tr id=newRows>';

    for(var i =1; i<=numofforces;i++)
    {
        var nearTr=$this.closest('tr');
        addRows=addRows + "<td>Force " +i+": </td><td><form><input type='text' name='forceItem' id='newR'/></form></td>";
    }

    addRows=addRows+"<td><div class='button' id='forceButton'> Add! </div></td></tr>";
    nearTr.after(addRows);
};

$('#forceButton').click(function(){
    forces=$("input[id='newR']").map(function(){
    return $(this).val()
});    

function forceRecording(numofforces,$this){
    var addRows='<tr id=newRows>';

    for(var i =1; i<=numofforces;i++)
    {
        var nearTr=$this.closest('tr');
        addRows=addRows + "<td>Force " +i+": </td><td><form><input type='text' name='forceItem' id='newR'/></form></td>";
    }

    addRows=addRows+"<td><div class='button' id='forceButton'> Add! </div></td></tr>";
    nearTr.after(addRows);
};

$('#forceButton').click(function(){
    forces=$("input[id='newR']").map(function(){
        return $(this).val()
    });

    prompt("forces");
});
```

As you can see my forceRecording function is working and creates a new row with new text input fields per the numofforces but once I try clicking the forceButton to enter the values into my forces array nothing happens. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You will be creating elements with the same ID (id='newR'). This is doomed to fail.

Comment: well some suggestions wouldn't hurt..

Comment: I did. Don't use the same ID for multiple things. That's a general tenet for computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing paranthesis around your code here

```
$('#forceButton').click(function(){
    forces=$("input[id='newR']").map(function(){return $(this).val()
});
```

It should be like this

```
$('#forceButton').click(function(){
   forces=$("input[id='newR']").map(function(){
       return $(this).val();
   });
});
```

And don't use the `id` instead use a `class name`

```
$('#forceButton').click(function(){
    forces=$(".newR").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Apply the class to input field like this

```
<input type="text" name="forceItem" class="newR"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to achieve, but maybe this will help:

```
function forceRecording(numofforces, $this) {
    var addRows = '<tr id="newRows">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= numofforces; i++)
        addRows += '<td>Force ' + i + ': </td><td><input type="text" name="forceItem" /></td>';
    addRows += '<td><input type="button" class="button" id="forceButton" value="Add!" /></td></tr>';
    $this.closest('tr').after(addRows);
}

$('#forceButton').click(function() {
    forces = $(this).parent().parent().filter('input[name="forceItem"]').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
});
```